# How To Create Script Tag That Add Custom Button In Cart Page?

Tags: shopify-app, script-tag

I have created an app using **[Shopify App Template - PHP](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-php)**,

**Shopify php+reactjs** app, but now I'm confused to create a script tag,
I don't understand how to create a script tag using Shopify App Template - PHP Structure,
exactly I don't understand which file I need to create that effect on the cart page.

I have read the script tag documentation, but don't get an exact idea about it,
I don't understand how to create a script tag, using Routes, Controller, and Component,
that the structure of this php App.

```
curl -d '{"script_tag":{"event":"onload","src":"https://example.com/my_script.js"}}' \
-X POST "https://your-development-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/script_tags.json" \
-H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: {access_token}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json
```

I used this code and run into the Postman, it's run but, but now where does the output display in the front end?

in "src": "https://example.com/my_script.js", in src, which exact URL I need to add?

because I'm developing this app in my local host.
please help me with this, give me some explanation on this.

Thank you.